# (Swift)Help me with 'DocumentReference' initialize error problem

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

```
  let saveDocument = Firestore.firestore()
  let docId = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "docId") as! String
    print(docId)
 if let documentRefString = saveDocument.collection("Posts").document(docId) {}
```

at **let documentRefString** error message camee out.

```
Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'DocumentReference'
```

Tell me How to fix this error.

Answer (score 1):

Remove if Let because `documentRefString` is  not optional ... and you cant apply `if let` on non optionals

```
saveDocument.collection("Posts").document(docId)
```

Does not return optional value so change this line to

```
let documentRefString = saveDocument.collection("Posts").document(docId)
```

And use `documentRefString` safely

Comment: What happened sir ?